# Is there an audio file format that doesn't contain metadata, so individual chunks can be split up at any position and just be saved to a file?

Tags: audio, file-type

Is there an audio file format, where I can save all the individual chunks ([recorded in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68867429/get-mediarecorder-audio-to-audio-ogg-blob-without-stopping-the-recorder)) while splitting them up at any point to save them to different files and have them still all playable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is what WAV file does ... if you save the file to conform to WAV payload format you can play back the file you create as a WAV file even without file having its normal 44 byte header

Answer (score 0):

I store raw audio data in arrays that can be sent to Web Audio API's [AudioBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer). The raw audio data arrays can be manipulated as you wish.

Specifics for obtaining the raw data are going to vary from language to language. I've not obtained raw data from within *JavaScript*. My experience comes from generating the data algorithmically or from reading .wav files with Java's `AudioInputLine`, and shipping the data to *JavaScript* via *Thymefeaf*.